# Hover on two elements using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, hover

I have two `<div>` elements attached to each other, I mean there is no space between them.

```html
<div id="box1">1</div>
<div id="box2">2</div>
```

And I have this jQuery code:

```js
$('#box1 , #box2').hover(function() {
  console.log("Hovered")
}, function() {
  console.log("Not")
});
```

My problem is when I move the mouse between box1 and box2, I still get on console log "Not".
I want those divs to be considered as one element so when I move the mouse between them I don't get on console log "Not".

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please share your whole html file result

Comment: So you want either-or?

Comment: The second argument is for the mouse out event, so it is going to be called when you mouse out on either element. If you want them treated as one put them into the same container and put the event on that parent element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

friend check the code below. I think it will work for you. As you have dai you have an absolute position div you must need a parent div and the parent div position must be relative. For doing that you have to add just a simple CSS code `position: relative;`. You also need to do some changes to your jquery code. You can just hover on the parent div and it will do your work. Hope this code will help you.

```js
//Box 1 Demo
$('#boxParrent1').hover(function() {
  console.log("Hovered")
}, function() {
  console.log("Not")
});

//Box 2 Demo
$('#boxParrent2').hover(function() {
  console.log("Hovered")
}, function() {
  console.log("Not")
});
```

```css
/*Main Code that are needed*/
#boxParrent1, #boxParrent2 {
    position: relative;
}




/*Codes Just used to give you a demo*/
#boxParrent1, #boxParrent2{
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
#boxParrent1{
    width: 200px;
}
#boxParrent2{
    width: 210px;
}
#box1, #box2, #box3, #box4{
 background: tomato;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 display: grid;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 font-family: Arial;
 font-size: 50px;
 color: #fff;
 cursor: pointer;
}
#box2, #box4{
  position:absolute;
  top: 0;
  left:100px;
  background: #02dce6;
}
#box4{
  left:110px;
  background: #02dce6;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="boxParrent1">
  <div id="box1">1</div>
  <div id="box2">2</div>
</div>

<div id="boxParrent2">
  <div id="box3">3</div>
  <div id="box4">4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

> I want those divs to be considered as one element

Well, quite simply, they aren't. And they can't be. That's not how HTML and CSS works.

The hover event is triggered one for each individual element bound to the event handler. And every time you leave one of those elements it will print the "not" output as per your instructions.

There is no "fix" for this in the exact way you described, but there are alternative approaches. An obvious solution is to wrap them both in an outer div and bind the hover event to that instead. Then the whole area *will* be considered as one element (because it literally is). Demo:

```js
$('#boxcontainer').hover(function() {
  console.log("Hovered")
}, function() {
  console.log("Not")
});
```

```css
#boxcontainer {
  border: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="boxcontainer">
  <div id="box1">1</div>
  <div id="box2">2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I already tried this solution but it's not working for me, Because one of the <div> is absolutely displayed.

Comment: You mean the boxes are not really adjacent, or something? And/or some positioning rules? You know, if you have a specific scenario like that, and there are things you already tried, then you should mention it clearly in your question then people don't suggest things which you tried, or which don't suit your situation. You tend to get answers to the question you asked, not the more complicated question which you didn't ask. We are not mind-readers. Please always provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) when asking. Thanks.

Comment: My bad, there isn't a gap between them, the container that contains those two div do not consider the absolute positioned div to exist

Comment: Please update your question to include all relevant details, including surrounding HTML and all relevant CSS rules which have any positioning effect on your divs. So that it works exactly as it does in your real page currently. Then we have some chance of understanding the precise situation and making a suggestion. (That's the kind of information which is meant by [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)).

Answer (score 1):

Try to place your 2 `div`'s in one super `div`

```
<div id="super">
   <div id="box1">1</div>
   <div id="box2">2</div>
</div>

$('#super').hover(function() {
   console.log("Hovered")
 }, function() {
   console.log("Not")
 });
```

Comment: I already tried this solution but it's not working for me, Because one of the <div> is absolutely displayed.